# Force field simulation with fixed vertices

Tags: cloth-simulation

can I do a force field simulation with some selected vertices fixed, so they are not affected by the simulation (see screenshots)? I am after a sort of crisp bag with the top and bottom edge welded together. Many thanks for any tips.

[image: fixe the selected vertices in place]

[image: run simulation]

Comment: I figured out to use the pin group in the shape tab. but this does not create the nice wrinkles like in the screen shot above.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re looking for a bag shape, I recommend using cloth physics with internal pressure. It was designed for just this purpose. If you’re looking for a way to merge two flat pieces together, I might actually start with a round piece like real chip bags are made of, and then use sewing to close up the edges. Additionally, to get the crisp edges that you would have on a chip bag (as opposed to a pillow) because the top and bottom are welded strips, you could use a vertex group to make that part of the fabric stiffer.

What you are doing here is not called a “force field simulation,“ but a “cloth simulation with a force field involved.“ further research should use these terms instead.

Comment: +1 A bag shape is probably the most common first result of playing with cloth physics. :)